# VBA - Save worksheet specific location for any user

Tags: vba, save

I'm trying to combine two codes into only one but I'm struggling to write the full code. Briefly, a user (with user id) will save one worksheet (of the workbook) to a specific location (for instance on his desktop), unique to everyone (because personal laptop). Her is first the code to save the worksheet on my desktop:

```
Sub create_file()
Dim LastRow As Long, LR As Long, lrow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Range("A2:B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:B" & LastRow)
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Y"
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("C2:I" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Paste for gA ASSA formula").Select
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
lrow = Sheets("Paste for gA ASSA formula").Cells.Find(What:="*",_ 
LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row - 3
Sheets("Formula for gA ASSAa").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & lrow)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formula for gA ASSAa").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\jeofbist3\Desktop\Deletion_Request" & 
Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

Here is the code to save the workbook on the existing location (no matter where):

```
Sub savefile()
Dim fname As String
fname = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
MsgBox (fname)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
End Sub
```

The best option would be to save it on the desktop of every user.. 
Does anyone have an idea? Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save something on users desktop, you should use this `"C:\users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop"` as path. And the user must have previliges to save something in this directory.